# How to Compile Mod_Python 3.3.1 for Python 2.6 and Apache 2.2 on Windows?

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

I have no experience compiling code other than using Visual Studio's Build command. I am hoping we can create a step by step guide for compiling mod_python on windows. Please be as descriptive as possible.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Download and install [python 2.6.2](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.2/python-2.6.2.msi)
2. Download and install [apache 2.2.11](http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/httpd/binaries/win32/apache_2.2.11-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8i.msi)
3. Download the most recent source code for mod_python from [svn](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/quetzalcoatl/mod_python/trunk/)

From here I'm lost to what the next step is. I've downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.

As mentioned by Hao I've already tried the tutorial mentioned in that link. Here is the error messages I'm receiving with that tutorial.

```
C:\mod_python\dist>build_installer.bat
Could Not Find C:\mod_python\src\*.obj
running bdist_wininst
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-2.6
creating build\lib.win32-2.6\mod_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\apache.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\mod
_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\cache.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\mod_
python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\cgihandler.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6
\mod_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\Cookie.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\mod
_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\importer.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\m
od_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\psp.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\mod_py
thon
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\publisher.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\
mod_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\python22.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\m
od_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\Session.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\mo
d_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\testhandler.py -> build\lib.win32-2.
6\mod_python
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\util.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\mod_p
ython
copying C:\mod_python\lib\python\mod_python\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.6\m
od_python
running build_ext
building 'mod_python_so' extension
creating build\temp.win32-2.6
creating build\temp.win32-2.6\Release
creating build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\mod_python
creating build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\mod_python\src
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -D_WINDOWS -IC:\mod_python\src\include -Ic:\apa
che\include -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Python26\PC /TcC:\mod_python\src\mod_pyth
on.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6\Release\mod_python\src\mod_python.obj
mod_python.c
c:\apache\include\ap_config.h(25) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
 'apr.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' fa
iled with exit status 2
```

Comment: Perhaps this question would be best answered on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: It looks like you're missing APR. http://apr.apache.org/compiling_win32.html

Comment: Any specific reason to use this odd combination of software?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/